# Salesforce - Google Calendar Syncing

Tags: apex, integration, callout, calendar, google

How can I sync salesforce calendar with google calendar using custom apex based way not through "Lightning Sync for Google" or any appxchange app. I could not see any blogs explaining the custom way to automate this syncing. Anyone who achieved the same using the custom apex way.

Comment: what have you researched or attempted on your own? As is, this question isn't asking a specific question - just for a solution for your problem (see [ask]). I would [edit] your question to be more specific on what part of this potential functionality you don't understand. Have you looked into [google calendar apis](https://developers.google.com/calendar)?